# Remove low frequency words

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, replace

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, 1 column has string of words, ex:

```
       Col1                 Col2
0       1          how to remove this word
1       5          how to remove the  word
```

I would like to remove all words that occurred once in the whole dataframe (threshold =1), I would get for example: (better if I can specify the threshold)

```
       Col1                 Col2
1       5          how to remove word
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks !

Comment: what have you tried? what is not working?

Comment: I created a serie with all the value counts, then created another serie with words under 1 occurence then tries the replace but got the whole column "None"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's try using a `Counter` here:

1. Split sentences into words
2. Compute global word frequency
3. Filter words based on computed frequencies
4. Join and re-assign

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

# split words into lists
v = df['Col2'].str.split().tolist() # [s.split() for s in df['Col2'].tolist()]
# compute global word frequency
c = Counter(chain.from_iterable(v))
# filter, join, and re-assign
df['Col2'] = [' '.join([j for j in i if c[j] > 1]) for i in v]
```

```
df
   Col1                Col2
0     1  how to remove word
1     5  how to remove word
```

Comment: I was just rolling my collections counter, but you beat me to it :-(

Comment: @AmiTavory Hah, sorry. You'll get the next one though, dw :D

Comment: The code is still running, is it possible to use pandas selection instead of use the iteration technique ?

Comment: @hdatas I'll tell you this type of iteration on strings is faster than pretty much anything pandas can give you. I'll guarantee my pandas badge this is faster than Wen's solution as well. If you have a lot of data, you should look into distributed processing with dask.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ok ill wait then :)

Comment: @hdatas Happy trails!

Answer (score 1):

Method from `get_dummies`

```
s=df.set_index('Col1').Col2.str.get_dummies(sep=' ')


s.loc[:,s.all()].stack().reset_index(level=1).groupby('Col1')['level_1'].apply(' '.join).reset_index(name='Col2')
Out[155]: 
   Col1                Col2
0     1  how remove to word
1     5  how remove to word
```

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ currently not have the problem , when I need the help will let my friends know :-)